# How to make an array out of the nth element of items in a 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays

Not sure how to google this for the same reason I am not sure how to write the title.

basically if I have the array:

```py
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I want to pull say the 2nd(nth) item of each array and turn them into an array as such:

```py
[2,5,8]
```

What is the quickest (preferably immediate) way to parse the array this way without using for-loops?

Comment: this will always require a loop.

Comment: edited to say for loops, thats what I really meant.

Comment: Just because you're hiding the loop behind an abstraction does not mean that it is not there @Laif

Comment: @Laif nope. All the answers here involve loops, even if they might be hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can use list comprehension

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
y = [ele[1] for ele in x]
```

- If you really don't want see `loop` or `for`, you can use `map` and `lambda`

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
y = list(map(lambda x:x[1],x))
```

Comment: This is close enough to what I meant I think, I'll mark it answered when I can

Answer (score 0):

If you don't consider a list comprehension a loop (even though it is certainly looping under the hood), you could accomplish this like:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
list2 = [ e[1] for e in list1 ]
```